# Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in cakephp controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp and tried to generate some CRUD operations with the console tool. It works fine except for one table (the biggest).

When trying to add a new element, it returns:

> Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
>   File: C:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\Controller\ChantiersController.php
>   Line: 50

Here is the line 50 and beyond:

```
    $programs = $this->Chantier->Program->find('list');
    $etats = $this->Chantier->Etat->find('list');
    $types = $this->Chantier->Type->find('list');
    $champsLibres = $this->Chantier->ChampsLibre->find('list');
    $feuillesDeRoutes = $this->Chantier->FeuillesDeRoute->find('list');
    $directionsPilotes = $this->Chantier->DirectionsPilote->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('programs', 'etats', 'types', 'champsLibres',    
            'feuillesDeRoutes', 'directionsPilotes'));
```

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($this->Chantier->Program);`

Comment: can you include line 49 just in case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TLDR / Answer:**

You can either fix the association, or load the model, and remove the through-call (the `->Chantier` portion:

```
$this->loadModel('Program');
$programs = $this->Program->find('list');
```

**Details / Explanation:**

That error basically means you're trying to call `find()` on a model that isn't loaded in the controller.

By default, the Controller's model is loaded.  And, as you're doing, you can use a model THROUGH a loaded model. (if the associations are set up correctly).

For example:

```
//ChantiersController
$this->Pizza->find('all'); //ERROR - Pizza model isn't loaded
```

To resolve this, just load the model prior to trying to use it:

```
$this->loadModel("Pizza");
$this->Pizza->find('all'); //All is good - loaded on the line above
```

In your case, since it looks like you're using associations with the `Chantier` model to find through other models, it's likely the association between the two models is not correct.

Comment: Without seeing your associations, it's quite impossible.  Might want to start a new question "Model associations not working" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the loadModel() function then you can define

```
var $uses = array('Program');
```

You can also mention other model names also in the array